# Please tell how this command checks whether rnum has an integer or not

Tags: shell-script, test

I saw a construct like this in a shell script, being used to test if `$rnum` is a number:

```shell
if ! [ "$rnum" -eq "$rnum" ] 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "rnum is not a number"
    exit 1
fi
```

It appears to work, but I don't understand why—shouldn't testing something for equality against itself always be true? How/why does that work?

Comment: Leaving out the `2>/dev/null` will give you an important clue: `-eq` expects its arguments to be integers and fails if that's not the case.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Why not make this an answer? I would not say it better.

Answer (score 0):

Ulrich Schwarz really did answer the question already in his comment. Just leave out the `2>/dev/null` and see what happens when `$rnum` is not an integer. Consider the following example written in an interactive `bash` session:

```
$ rnum='foo'
$ [ "$rnum" -eq "$rnum" ]
-bash: [: foo: integer expression expected
$ echo $?
2
```

If you are looking for an alternative method for testing whether a value is an integer, Prashant Band already gave one. However, I prefer a more portable solution (one that doesn't rely on the `=~` operator):

```
expr "X$rnum" : 'X[-+]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}$' >/dev/null || {
    echo 'rnum is not a number' >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Note that weird values like `-0`, `+0`, and `000` are treated as integers. However, this is the same behavior you'd get using the original construct presented in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This script checks if it is number or not:

```
num=123
if [[ "$num" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
echo "It is Number"
fi
```

Comment: The OP wants to know of **their** command works.